# ¿Puedo crear una nueva rama Git a partir de un "commit" anterior?

Tags: git

Estoy haciendo algunas pruebas de regresión buscando un error que introduje en un proyecto, básicamente clonando el repositorio actual, eliminando x *commits* y probando a ver donde apareció en error... Quería explorar otras alternativas.

Lo habitual es crear nuevas ramas a partir del momento actual de trabajo en el repositorio y en éste momento desearía haber creado una nueva rama x *commits* atrás... Como no lo hice, quisiera saber si **es posible crear una nueva rama a partir de un *commit* determinado**, por ejemplo de 4 commits atrás... ¿alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes utilizar esta opción:

```
git branch <nombre-rama> <sha1-commit>
```

también es válido utilizar referencia simbólicas, pero esta opción es la uso a diario, me parece más simple y flexible.

Answer (score 8):

Aunque la respuesta de Nicolas responde directamente a tu pregunta, siendo que estás buscando formas alternativas de aíslar el commit que introdujo un defecto en tu proyecto, te sugiero de investigar el uso de [git bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect).

`git bisect` está diseñado precisamente para conseguir de forma óptima (usando una búsqueda binaria) el commit que introdujo un problema.

Para que funcione correctamente, debes proveer 2 puntos de referencia iniciales:

1. un commit que se sepa incluya el defecto (probablemente el commit actual)
2. un commit que definitivamente no incluya el defecto

Por ejemplo, digamos que sabes que en tu rama actual tienes el problema. Y aunque no sabes en cual commit preciso apareció el problema, estás seguro de que hace 100 commits (por decir algo) el problema no existía. Entonces comenzarías la investigación de la siguiente forma:

```
git bisect start
git bisect bad
git bisect good abc123def456
```

... donde `git bisect bad` indica que el commit actual tiene el problema, y `git bisect good abc123def456` indica que por lo menos estás seguro que el problema no existía en el commit `abc123def456`.

Con esta información en mano, git ahora automáticamente escoge (usando el algoritmo de búsqueda binaria) un commit al que le hace un checkout.

Ahora te toca a ti probar ese commit para ver si el defecto existe o no.  Si el commit escogido tiene el defecto, entonces debes indicarlo con el comando:

```
git bisect bad
```

Pero si el commit no tiene el defecto, entonces debes indicarlo con:

```
git bisect good
```

Según lo que respondas, ahora git automáticamente escoge otro commit al que le hace un checkout. Y nuevamente, te toca probar este commit para ver si el defecto está presente o no, y debes indicarlo con `git bisect bad` o `git bisect good`.

Este proceso sigue de forma sucesiva (y de forma binaria para minimizar la cantidad de commits que necesites examinar) hasta que eventualmente git te indica cual es el commit culpable de haber introducido el defecto.

Finalmente, una vez la investigación concluída, terminas con:

```
git bisect reset
```

... y estó te regresa a tu estado inicial antes de haber empezado el `git bisect`.

Comment: Doy por buena la respuesta del compañero, porque tal y como esta planteada mi pregunta es la respuesta correcta. Lo que planteas me parece muy interesante. No conocía esta opción en absoluto. Un saludo.